# PHP Unserialize and Accessing array

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have some complex data I want serialized.

When I tried to unserialize it, all I got was this:

```
bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)...etc...
```

This is the serialized string:

```
a:6:{i:0;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"1";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"REG";s:8:"ItemName";s:21:"Inscrição Masculina";s:8:"ItemCost";s:4:"9.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-12";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"1";}i:1;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"3";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"REG";s:8:"ItemName";s:36:"Inscrição Feminina (oferta jersey)";s:8:"ItemCost";s:4:"9.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-12";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}i:2;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"4";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"MLS";s:8:"ItemName";s:8:"Almoços";s:8:"ItemCost";s:4:"5.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-12";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}i:3;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:2:"13";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"MDS";s:8:"ItemName";s:16:"Jersey Masculino";s:8:"ItemCost";s:5:"10.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-13";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}i:4;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:2:"14";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"MDS";s:8:"ItemName";s:35:"Calção Ciclismo Alusivo ao Evento";s:8:"ItemCost";s:5:"28.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-16";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}i:5;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:2:"11";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"DSC";s:8:"ItemName";s:72:"Desconto de 1€ por ter licença de Competição/Betetista/Cicloturista";s:8:"ItemCost";s:5:"-1.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-13";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}}
```

I'm trying to use this:

```
$temp = unserialize(utf8_encode($dataArr[6]));
var_dump($temp);
```

In this site, when I paste my serialized data, everything comes out nice:

http://www.unserialize.com/s/4bc6dd21-e7ab-8189-ba1d-00002a57a4cb

Thank you

Comment: You do realize your code is commented out?

Comment: Yes I do. I've been testing alot. I tested it without comments.

Comment: Ok - I have commented it in again

Comment: Have you tried without `utf8_encode`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `utf8_encode`.

If `$dataArr` is your string then you have to unserialize it before accessing variables in the array.

```
$dataArr = 'a:6:{i:0;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"1";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"REG";s:8:"ItemName";s:21:"Inscrição Masculina";s:8:"ItemCost";s:4:"9.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-12";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"1";}i:1;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"3";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"REG";s:8:"ItemName";s:36:"Inscrição Feminina (oferta jersey)";s:8:"ItemCost";s:4:"9.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-12";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}i:2;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"4";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"MLS";s:8:"ItemName";s:8:"Almoços";s:8:"ItemCost";s:4:"5.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-12";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}i:3;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:2:"13";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"MDS";s:8:"ItemName";s:16:"Jersey Masculino";s:8:"ItemCost";s:5:"10.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-13";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}i:4;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:2:"14";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"MDS";s:8:"ItemName";s:35:"Calção Ciclismo Alusivo ao Evento";s:8:"ItemCost";s:5:"28.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-16";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}i:5;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:2:"11";s:11:"ItemEventID";s:1:"1";s:7:"ItemCat";s:3:"DSC";s:8:"ItemName";s:72:"Desconto de 1€ por ter licença de Competição/Betetista/Cicloturista";s:8:"ItemCost";s:5:"-1.00";s:12:"ItemCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:8:"ItemFree";s:1:"N";s:9:"ItemStart";s:9:"2013-1-13";s:7:"ItemEnd";s:8:"2013-4-7";s:7:"ItemQty";s:1:"0";}}';

$temp = unserialize($dataArr);

//Now you can access every element with its index.
var_dump($temp[0]);
var_dump($temp[1]);
var_dump($temp[2]);
var_dump($temp[3]);
var_dump($temp[4]);
var_dump($temp[5]);
```

Comment: What do you mean with access each variable? When I try what you've asked in the question with your data it works when I remove utf8_encode.

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't know how to access each variable in the array!

Comment: It doesn't help when you bring the exact same comment again. Where do you want to access a variable in the array? I can't find anything like that in the question. Have you posted the complete code? I thought `$dataArr[6]` is the string with your serialized array.

Comment: Hmm, I think I kind of know what's happening.

That info, is what I'm retrieving from the database.

If I do this:

$temp = unserialize('raw data....');
var_dump($temp);
It works.
But with this:

$temp = unserialize($dataArr[6]);
var_dump($temp);

It doesn't work..

Maybe I'm missing a cast?

Comment: if `$dataArr` is the array you've posted in a serialized version then you can't access it with an index before unserializing it. What exactly is in `$dataArr`?

Comment: $dataArr is a result query from the database, and in index 6, is the serialized data. That is why I use unserialize($dataArr[6]).

Comment: Then whats the exact output of `$dataArr[6]` if you `echo` it?

Comment: This, that's why it's driving me crazy!!!

a:6:{i:0;a:10:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"1";s:11:"ItemEventI..........